# Clang-format: enable formatting only for code fragments

Tags: c++, clang-format

Is there any way to format only code fragments?
I use a big file, which contains some text, descriptions and cpp code.
For cpp code we use tags  and , for example:

```
some text, lalala
<cpp>
int a =5;
</cpp>
some text, lololo
```

So I need to format only code between `<cpp>` and `</cpp>`.
Is it real with Clang-format?

Comment: If the text portion allows some kind of comment, you could try `/* clang-format off */` at the top of the file, then `/* clang-format on */` in the cpp tag start, and at the cpp tag end again `off`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I know this trick, but maybe there is any possibility to use only clang-format rules without file modification?

Comment: I don't think it is possible out of the box. But you can tell clang-format to format only specific lines, e.g. via the `--lines` command line option. So you could probably write a little script that retrieves the lines of the cpp portions and then calls clang-format with those line numbers.